# Date Filter Will Not Pop Up in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build an RShiny Dashboard for baseball data, however, I cannot seem to get any dates to pop up in my date filter.

Here is what is going on:
[image]

For whatever reason it is not working, if somebody could help me figure this out, that would be great.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(DT)
   


# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    column(10, offset = 1,
           titlePanel("Gopher Dashboard")),
    column(2, tags$img(src = "gophs.png", height = 150, width = 150), align = "center"),
    fluidRow(
        column(10, offset = 1, h3(strong("Pitcher Summary Table")), dataTableOutput("pitcher_summary_table"), align = "center")
    ), br(), br(), 
    fluidRow(
        column(2,selectInput("name","Select Pitcher", choices = unique(s2020$player_name))),
        column(2, selectInput(inputId = "GameInput", label = "Select Game", choices = "")),
        wellPanel(style = "background: white; border-color:black; border-width:2px",
                  fluidRow( 
                      column(4, h2(strong(textOutput("selected_pitcher"))), style = "padding-right:0px;"),
                      column(8, h2("Pitcher Report"), h2(textOutput("selected_game")), align = "right", style = "padding-left:0px;")),
                  fluidRow(
                      column(4, plotOutput("movement"), align = "center"), 
                          fluidRow(
                              column(4, plotOutput("usage"), align = "center", offset = 1)
                          )
                      )     
                  ), br(), br(), br()
        ), br(),
        p(em("Usage for the University of Minnesota Baseball Team"), align = "center")
    )


# Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$PitcherInput, 
                 updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "GameInput", label = "Select Game", 
                                   choices = sort(unique(s2020$game_date.x[s2020$player_name == input$name]))))
    
    output$selected_pitcher <- renderText({paste(input$name)})
    
    output$selected_game <- renderText({paste(input$GameInput)})
    
    output$pitcher_summary_table <- renderDataTable({
        table <- s2020 %>%
            filter(player_name == input$name, game_date.x == input$GameInput) %>%
            group_by('Pitch' = pitch_type) %>%
            summarize('No.' = n(),
                      'Max Velo (MPH)' = round(max(release_speed, na.rm = TRUE),1),
                      'Avg. Velo (MPH)' = round(mean(release_speed, na.rm = TRUE),1))
        
        tableFilter <- reactive({table})
        datatable(tableFilter(), options = list(dom = 't', columnDefs = list(list(targets = 0, visible = FALSE)))) %>%
            formatStyle(c(1,2), `border-left` = "solid 1px") %>% formatStyle(c(2,5,7), `border-right` = "solid 1px")
    })
    
    sc_reactive = reactive({
        s2020 %>% 
            dplyr::filter(player_name == input$name,
                          game_date.x == input$GameInput)
    })
    
    output$movement <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(sc_reactive(), aes(-pfx_x, pfx_z, color = pitch_type)) +
            geom_point(size = 4) +
            geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
            geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
            ylim(-2.5,2.5) + xlim(-2.5,2.5) +
            guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'Pitch Type')) +
            xlab("Horizontal Movement") +
            ylab("Vertical Movement") +
            ggtitle("Pitch Movement") +
            ylab("Induced Vertical Break") +
            xlab("Horizontal Break")
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here is a snippet of my data:

```
> dput(head(n2))

structure(list(pitch_type = c("FF", "SL", "FF", "SL", "FF", "SL"
), game_date.x = structure(c(18477, 18493, 18472, 18493, 18477, 
18521), class = "Date"), release_speed = c(99.2, 88.2, 96.5, 
88.4, 98.3, 92.1), release_pos_x = c(-0.87, -2.03, -1.8, -1.8, 
-1.03, -1.32), release_pos_z = c(5.62, 5.52, 5.71, 5.66, 5.63, 
5.64), player_name = c("deGrom, Jacob", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", 
"Cole, Gerrit", "deGrom, Jacob", "deGrom, Jacob"), pfx_x = c(-0.53, 
0.46, -1, 0.53, -0.56, 0.33), pfx_z = c(1.39, 0.18, 1.54, 0.28, 
1.33, 0.52), plate_x = c(1.26, 1.47, -0.54, 0.57, -0.34, 0.34
), plate_z = c(1.86, -0.14, 2.32, 2.11, 3.3, 1.88), release_spin_rate = c(2333L, 
2571L, 2509L, 2496L, 2443L, 2687L), release_extension = c(7, 
6.5, 6.7, 6.3, 7, 6.8), spin_axis = c(218L, 105L, 220L, 141L, 
212L, 161L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you do a couple things to help us help you?  Please try to isolate your problem--strip out the stuff from your app that's not necessary to recreate your problem and post that code.  Same goes for your data--instead of posting the structure of the whole thing post the results of `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))`.

Comment: @BenG Just made the changes, sorry about that!